# Can I get Fiktionsbescheinigung outside Germany in the EU after schengen expires?

Tags: schengen, germany, us-citizens, residency, residence-permits

I'm in another Schengen country in the EU waiting for a residence permit. But I changed my plans because now I want to go to Germany to study.

Since I don't have the residence permit yet, I can't travel from this country.

Since I have been waiting, I'm technically still in schengen. But I'm here legally under this country's laws, as I am waiting for the permit.

It will take more months because I need to get documents apostilled from the USA.

The residency permit is backdated to the time of application. But I want to go to Germany now.

I want to apply for a German residency permit that I am eligible for. I cannot go to Germany to get it because I'm in this country. I can apply at the German embassy in this country, because I cannot enter German on a Schengen visa, which I think it counts as expired until my current residency permit goes through, which will take too long.

If I can go to Germany, then  I would then cancel the residency permit for this country.

Can I, after applying for the residency permit I'm eligible for, while it is processing, get a Fiktionsbescheinigung and go to Germany immediately?

Comment: Are you a US citizen?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Yes. I'm a US citizen.

Comment: Please add: which country you are presently in and that you are a US citizen to the question. In short: as a US citizen you can apply for a residence permit directly in Germany. While in county X, after you applied for that residence permit the 90 day clock has stopped. Once you leave that country, it will start again. Since you don't require a visa as a US citizen you can go to Germany on your passport alone (take the proof of residence permit application with you). Apply for residence permit on arrival.

Comment: I spoke with the German embassy, and they told me that I have to apply for the German visa in my home country, or wait for my current residency permit to complete in order to apply in this country. They also told me that if I went directly to Germany, they would not give me a residence permit while in Germany; I would have to return to my home country to retrieve it.

Comment: How long exactly have you been waiting for your residence permit application? And did you enter this country using visa waivers or with an actual Schengen visa?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy There are no problems with me residing in my current country, I can stay as long as it takes, like the police told me, "even if it takes a year" to process. My application is accepted now but I am awaiting documents. It will take months longer to get the background check apostilled. I entered before this country was Schengen, so neither.

Comment: @traveladdict What a wierd statement and contradicts what other German Mission sites state ([United Kingdom: D-visa: Residence permits for employment - Federal Foreign Office](https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/visa/-/2449340) or what the Berlin Immigration Office states ([Legal entry without visa for nationals of certain countries - Berlin.de](https://www.berlin.de/einwanderung/en/entry/visa-extension/artikel.1049085.en.php)). Thankfully judges have the last say in such matters and they can read a simple paragraph of law.

Comment: Mark, what is your interpretation of the section "Traveling in the Schengen area" at the end of the second link you provided? `If your nationality entitles you to enter for a short stay without a visa, you can travel to the following countries in the Schengen area for no more than 90 days within a period of 180 days:

Austria, Belgium, Croatia, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Sweden, Switzerland, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain `

Comment: @traveladdict For persons who require a visa a residence permit serves as a visa replacement - but not in cases for of a first application (Article 2 (16)(b)(i) Schengen Border Code). A person who does not require a visa is not effected by this since their passport alone allows them to enter.

Comment: How about the fact that paragraph clearly states about no more than 90 days in Schengen.

Comment: @traveladdict What about it? When you left the Schengen Area in December 2022 the day count stopped. With the Croatian national stamp you were granted a **seperate** 90 days in Croatia. As part of the transition period, entry granted under the old rules remain in effect 'in order to avoid travel becoming more difficult for certain categories of persons.' (see point (8) of the [Council decision on the full application of the provisions of the Schengen acquis in the Republic of Croatia](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32022D2451) (EU) 2022/2451 of 2022-12-08.

Comment: @traveladdict You are making any answer more difficult to make by not naming the country you are in. If Croatia is that country there are transition rules in place to avoid criminalizing people. Naming the country is **relevant** to answering the question, so should be included in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes. I'm a US citizen

As a US citizen you can apply for a residence permit directly in Germany  based on §41(1) AufenthV.

See answer where §41(1) AufenthV is quoted:

- [Can I enter Germany as a tourist without a return flight with my German husband and kids and apply for family reunion visa there?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179493/can-i-enter-germany-as-a-tourist-without-a-return-flight-with-my-german-husband/179495#179495)

You can apply for **any** type of residence permit.

The 90 day rule **does not** apply for the time in country X once the application for their residence permit has been made.

Once you leave that country, it will start again.

Since you don't require a Schengen visa (Type C) as a US citizen you can go to Germany on your passport alone (take the proof of residence permit application for country X with you, which is proof that you were in country X based on their national law).

Apply for the German residence permit on arrival.

> according to the German embassy, because they said I am NOT considered a resident until I have the actual residence permit, until then I am considered a visitor and must apply from my home country.

The Embassy is correct that you cannot apply for a **national visa** in country X until you are a resident of country X (i.e. while the application is pending).

But you do not need a national visa (Type D) for Germany due to §41(1) AufenthV.

> They also told me that if I went directly to Germany, they would not give me a residence permit while in Germany; I would have to return to my home country to retrieve it.

That information is not correct for citizens of the countries listed in §41 AufenthV.

Comment: I think there is a hint ("waiting for months") in the question that the 90 day timer for Schengen visa waiver has expired and that is why this person cannot move inside the Schengen area, and also why they cannot enter Germany to apply for a residence permit, and also why the German authorities will not give them a residence permit either. So your answer is incorrect for this case.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy National residence laws **overrides** the Schengen rules. While waiting for the application for the residence permit of country X, the OP is allowed to stay in that country accourding to the **national laws** of that country (which the OP still hasn't stated). For the other Schengen States it is if the OP is **outside** of the Schengen Area in as far as the 90 day rule is concerned.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy That is why the OP is **wrong** in believing that he cannot go, with the US passport, to Germany. Also §41(1) AufenthV states **explicidly** that US citizens can 'enter the federal territory without a visa and stay there. A required residence permit can be obtained in Germany.' That is why you are **wrong** in stating   'also why the German authorities will not give them a residence permit either.'.

Comment: That only works if the residence permit is issued, not if its still pending. Even worse if its rejected. Do not forget that Schengen rules are part of national law of EU member states. Also funny to mention national law when the OP has not mentioned in which country they applied for a residence permit.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy That is not correct. In Germany a **Fiktionsbescheinigung** (the assumtion (fiction) that the residence permit will be granted) can be issued when the application is made. What is true, is that persons that **require** a (Type C) Schengen Visa to enter the Schengen Area **cannot**  use this as a visa replacement during the intitial residence permit application. US citizens, however, do not require a (Type C) Schengen Visa so this does not apply to them (or anyone else that do not require a Schengen Visa).

Comment: The OP is not in Germany, he cannot be issued a Fiktionsbescheinigung outside of Germany. You seem to misunderstand the situation.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Since the OP had not stated in which country they are in, Germany was given as an example where the assumtion that the residence permit will be granted exists (since you seem to be compleatly oblivious of this, just as you fail to understand that the laws about visiting and residence **are two compleatly different things**, the latter based soly under national law).

Comment: I'm not in Germany. I'm in another schengen country waiting final documents. My residency application was accepted but I need to wait for the documents to be issued the permit. Unfortunately, apostille of my background check can take 3 months.

Comment: @traveladdict Yes, that is known. That is why the answer uses **country X**, since we don't know which country you are actually in.

Comment: If §41(1) AufenthV really means I can enter Germany with expired schengen as a US citizen (if the time in schengen was not in Germany, which it wasn't), then all my problems are solved. I'm not going to try it though until I get a confirmation from Germany immigration.

Comment: @traveladdict Or call the Embassy and ask again referring to §41(1) AufenthV. They probably just didn't take that exception into consideration when you first asked.

Comment: @traveladdict This is also confirmed here: [Residence Visa / Long Stay Visa - Federal Foreign Office - German Missions USA](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/visa/residence-visa/922288) *Info: Citizens of the United States of America may also apply for their residence permit **after** entering Germany **without a visa**.*

Comment: Yes but the concern here is can I enter with expired Schengen visa. I need to check with Germany immigration and get a written confirmation. Can't risk it.

Comment: And that's what I'm going to do tomorrow. They are closed right now. First thing tomorrow I will call and confirm and request a written confirmation.

Comment: @traveladdict When you do, use the correct terminology. Tell them when you entered Croatia and that on date X you applied for a residence permit (for which I assume you have some form of confirmation) and thus are there under national law. (As a US citizen you **do not** have a Schengen visa, but entered, visa free, based only on the 90 day rule)

Comment: Yes I have confirmation of my application as well as receipts for my rent during my stay here. And considering schengen has run out, it should be clear I haven't left this country. Anyway, I think when you stay in Germany they register you with the German authorities, proving I haven't been to Germany. But this country is schengen now.

Comment: If they confirm it, I will accept this answer.

Comment: I confirmed that § 41(1) is correct, BUT -- it could cause problems and could get in trouble if the German police do not know or are not willing to consider this. The German immigration employee said they were instructed to tell people that they should not go by that, because it could cause confusion and get in trouble. So they said yes, technically it can be ok, but if you are in Germany without documents, you could get in trouble, even though the law technically does say that. It is better to apply outside Germany.