# Will transit through another Schengen country to a country that allows visa-free stay cause overstaying Schengen?

Tags: schengen, transit, overstaying, residency

I'm planning on going to Germany. I'm in a Schengen country awaiting a residency permit which is accepted but not issued and won't be for months due to needing to apostille the background check.

If I wait for the permit to be issued, it's backdated from the time of application and therefore I have not overstayed schengen.

This country has a law allowing me to stay indefinitely while the application is in process.

But since it is in Schengen, I've been waiting for months and if I left, technically I've been in Schengen for more than 90 days, and don't have the residence permit yet.

Germany has a law that it looks like as a US citizen, I can stay visa-free up to 90 days. If this means Schengen doesn't apply, then I can go immediately.

But I have to get there. If I take the bus, there are no border checks within Schengen, and I will save hundreds of dollars. I'm not going to risk it if it's not technically legal though. I not going to risk a ban over a few hundred dollars.

If I fly, I will have to pay a lot of money due to my luggage and much higher cost of the flight versus a bus. My luggage is only a few dollars to take on the bus. It's hundreds on the flight and Ill have to throw away things to lighten it.

So I'm wondering if even the simple transit through another Schengen country if I took the bus would constitute overstaying since I don't have the residence permit yet, even though I'm in this country legally and still had time left on Schengen when I put my application in?

Comment: "If this means Schengen doesn't apply, then I can go immediately": it doesn't mean that.  The German 90 days is not separate from the Schengen 90 days.  There's no difference whether you fly or take a bus.

Comment: Again, someone is saying the opposite of what others are saying. I've received so many opposite answers that I can't trust anything anyone says that isn't from the German government.

Comment: What source do you have that suggests that Germany allows 90 days separately from the Schengen 90 days?  There are some countries that have bilateral agreements with this effect (for example, Poland has such an agreement applying to US citizens), but Germany is not among them as far as I know.  (Have you considered applying for a German D visa at a German consulate in Croatia?  It might not be possible before your residence permit is issued, or at all for US citizens, but if it is possible it will let you travel there as soon as it is issued.)

Comment: It's possible to read section 41 of the [Aufenthaltsverordnung](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/BJNR294510004.html) as permitting entry when the Schengen days are exhausted, provided that you are planning to apply for a German residence permit.  Indeed, on its face, it does seem to be a separate 90 days, but I do not know whether the German authorities interpret it that way.  If I were you, I'd want to be sure of that before planning to rely on it.

Comment: I confirmed the answer is YES according to § 41(1). BUT -- it could cause problems and could get in trouble if the German police do not know or are not willing to consider this. The German immigration employee said they were instructed to tell people that they should not go by that, because it could cause confusion and get in trouble. So they said yes, technically it can be ok, but if you are in Germany without documents, you could get in trouble, even though the law technically does say that. It is better to apply outside Germany.

Comment: Confirmed how, with whom?  By speaking with someone from a German immigration office?  In any event, with this information I would agree that it's safer to fly into Germany than to try to travel through Slovenia and Austria.  But even then you should keep in mind that you'll be going through Croatian and German passport control if you fly before March 26th.  Why is the apostille taking so long?

Comment: By German immigration authorities at an immigration office. Apostille regularly takes this long from the USA due to a backlog and shutting down all in-person services (since 2020) so that even 3rd party providers are not faster. I was surprised and annoyed about the very long wait times.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: this answer applies only to citizens of countries who do not need a (Type C) Schengen Visa to enter the Schengen Area **and** are allowed to apply for a residence permit inside the country in question.

For the time starting at the residence permit application, your stay is based on that countries **national law** (the Schengen 90 day rule **does not apply** during that period while inside that country).

> I entered before this country was Schengen, ...
>
> - From: [Can I get Fiktionsbescheinigung outside Germany in the EU after schengen expires? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179836/can-i-get-fiktionsbescheinigung-outside-germany-in-the-eu-after-schengen-expires/179847?noredirect=1#comment456535_179836)

If Croatia (assumed based on a comment made elsewhere) is the country in question and you entered before the 1st of January 2023, then the time in Croatia before the 1st of January also does not count (you left, what was then, the Schengen Area).

If you applied for the residence permit on the 15th of December 2022, then the time after the 1st of January 2023 also does not count since you were in Croatia under national law when Croatia became part of the Schengen Area.

Also, if you entered Croatia on the 1st of December 2022 and was granted the standard Croatian 90 days in Croatia, that period would end around the 1st of March. You would then have a Schengen exit stamp and a Croatian national entry stamp. The last day that counts for the Schengen 90 days would be the date of the Schengen exit stamp.

> This country has a law allowing me to stay indefinitely while the application is in process.

The date of that application will be used as the 'exit' stamp replacement, the date upon entry to another Schengen country will be the new 'entry' stamp date (assuming that anyone makes the effort to check) for the day count calculation.

When that result is under 90 days, then it will not be considered an overstay.

Comment: "If you applied for the residence permit on the 15th of December 2022, then the time after the 1st of January 2023 also does not count since you were in Croatia under national law when Croatia became part of the Schengen Area.": On what do you base this conclusion?  It looks wrong to me.

Comment: @phoog Because the national law allows you to stay until a final decision on the residence permit has been made.

Comment: @phoog Also, if the OP entered Croatia in December 2022 and was granted the standard Croatian 90 days in Croatia, that period would end around the 1st of March. The OP would have a Schengen exit stamp and a Croatian national entry stamp. The last day that counts for the Schengen 90 days would be the date of the Schengen exit stamp.

Comment: "Because the national law allows you to stay until a final decision on the residence permit has been made": but that doesn't mean that the submission of the application stops the 90-day clock. By analogy, look at the way bilateral agreements work. A US citizen can stay in e.g. Poland even after the 90 Schengen days are used up (in other Schengen countries) because of a bilateral agreement. So it's possible to go to Germany for 90 days and then Poland for 90 days, where the time in Poland is authorized by national law. But the time in Poland also uses up Schengen days if they're (continued)...

Comment: ... not yet exhausted, so a US citizen can't go to Poland for 90 days and then to Germany. I suspect that OP is correct that the 90 Schengen days are exhausted and it will be necessary either to wait for the residence permit or to leave the Schengen area for 90 days before going to Germany.

Comment: @phoog See **Guidelines on calculation of the length of stay**, in point 3.6 of the Practical Handbook for Border Guards: *However, it is **out of the scope of the Schengen acquis** to regulate situations of **continuous, uninterrupted stay in the Schengen State that go beyond 90 days in one Schengen State**. This falls under **national law** or bilateral agreements and in such cases the Schengen State concerned should follow its national rules on prolongation/extension of stay.*

Comment: @phoog I think the situation for multiple short term stays (such as with Poland->US and Germany->Australia [The German-Australian Agreement on the Exemption of Visa Requirements, dated 22.12.1952 - Federal Foreign Office](https://australien.diplo.de/au-en/service/01-visa/short-term-visa/2073662)) are treated differently than cases authorising residence.

Comment: @phoog Also the SBC Article 8 (3)(a): *checks on entry shall comprise verification of the conditions governing entry laid down in Article 6(1) and, where applicable, of documents authorising residence ...*. It does not use the term residence permit (which would exclude 'temporary permits issued pending examination of a first application for a residence permit').

Comment: I confirmed the answer is YES according to § 41(1). BUT -- it could cause problems and could get in trouble if the German police do not know or are not willing to consider this. The German immigration employee said they were instructed to tell people that they should not go by that, because it could cause confusion and get in trouble. So they said yes, technically it can be ok, but if you are in Germany without documents, you could get in trouble, even though the law technically does say that. It is better to apply outside Germany.

Comment: Note that if a German border control does not agree then you could be banned from Schengen for 2 years for overstaying, and it may not be worth the hassle to fight it legally. Especially if there is another way.

Comment: @traveladdict it sounds like the safest thing to do would be either to wait for the residence permit or leave the Schengen area and wait 90 days.  Mark Johnson: I don't see that language in the October 2022 version of the document (https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-11/Practical%20handbook%20for%20border%20guards_en.pdf), but the fact that it used to be in there is encouraging.

Comment: @phoog It should be noted this document is a schengen document from Brussels, NOT a German document and does not address German internal policy.

Comment: @phoog Yes, after posting that I checked for a newer version and found the November 2022 one that has been rewritten in preparation for the Entry/Exit system. Also new was the statement: *National rules or practices which lay down that a third-country national must as a general rule leave its territory after termination of a long-stay (covered by a residence permit or national visa) before being allowed to start a subsequent short-term stay on that territory are not compatible with Schengen rules.*

Comment: @traveladdict Do you actually have a Schengen exit stamp and a Croatian national entry stamp (I assume dated in December 2022) in your passport?

Comment: Of course I have a Schengen exit stamp and an entry stamp to the country I am in. I exited Schengen and entered the country I am in, and there was border control for Schengen, which stamped my passport. I first had to go to a first border control to exit Schengen. After that, I immediately had to approach a second border control for entry into the country I am in.

Comment: @phoog Assuming Croatia is the country in question, there are transition rules in place for those who entered before 2023-01-01. (See point (8) of the [Council decision on the full application of the provisions of the Schengen acquis in the Republic of Croatia](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32022D2451) COUNCIL DECISION (EU) 2022/2451 of 2022-12-08). Therefore the Schengen exit stamp and the Croatian national entry stamp of 2022 must be taken into acount.